# Find the transaction cost-adjusted expected return of the stock

Tags: finance, economics

Let $W^b_i$ denote the weight of stock i in the existing portfolio and $W^a_i$ denote the weight of stock i in the new portfolio to be created. Let $c_i$ denote the transaction cost of stock $i$.

If $m_i$ is the expected return of stock $i$, what is the transaction cost-adjusted expected return of the stock $i$. Please help me with this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome, you may want to include what you know or have tried so far to promote discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The cost-adjusted expected return is the expected return, minus the transaction costs. The total size of your trade is $|W_i^b - W_i^a|$ and the cost per unit is $c_i$. The transaction cost adjusted return is the expected return, minus the total cost of doing the trade.